# Slow DNS resolution on ubuntu 16.04 / 17.10 on certain network

Tags: 16.04, networking, 17.10, dns

I'm running multiple Ubuntu instances on my home network (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop 16.04 and just tried 17.10). I'm seeing an issue on my home network that DNS resolution takes ages.

How am I sure it's DNS?

1. ssh to a domainname takes very long, ssh to an ip is instant.
2. Chrome is stuck on every webpage on 'Resolving Host'.
3. `sudo apt update` is incredibly slow on every target.

I don't see this issue when I take my laptop to work on another network. But I'm still sure the issue lays with Ubuntu as when I boot into Windows I'm not seeing that kind of problem. Also I'm getting a consistent 200/25Mbit when speedtest is able to connect.

When I run the dig command to app.kayzr.com I get the following response:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> app.kayzr.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 47866
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;app.kayzr.com.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
app.kayzr.com.      599 IN  A   52.174.137.77

;; Query time: 63 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Sat Jan 20 16:04:15 UTC 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 58
```

ssh to the server though takes ages and surfing to the website show me 7 seconds waiting time before I get the initial file load.

I've tried tingering with resolv.conf, with NetworkManager but it seems that none is helping.

Comment: I also want to add, dns resolution is even slow on bash on ubuntu on windows.